React - cursor escaping boundaries of textarea on iOS
I have a PWA chat app built with Nextjs and I'm seeing this bug. The textarea height is dynamically resized to accommodate longer messages.
I can't 100% reliably reproduce the bug, but quickly typing or deleting multiple lines seems to do it. I've also been unable to reproduce it at all on Android.
bug example
bug example 2
I've tried adjusting the padding and removing the rows prop, and the problem is seemingly isolated to iOS.
Code for the component:
import { Textarea, TextareaProps } from '@/components/ui/textarea'
import { useBounds } from '@/hooks/bounds'
import { cn } from '@/utils/utils'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

interface IProps extends TextareaProps {
  isLoading?: boolean
  formRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>
}

export const Input = ({ className, isLoading, formRef, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const textarea = ref.current

      textarea.style.height = '0px'

      const scrollHeight = textarea.scrollHeight

      textarea.style.height = scrollHeight + 'px'
    }
  }, [ref, rest.value])

  const { isDesktop } = useBounds()

  return (
    <Textarea
      rows={1}
      ref={ref}
      onKeyDown={e => {
        if(isDesktop && e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
          e.preventDefault();
          formRef?.current?.requestSubmit();
        }
      }}
      className={cn('resize-none overflow-y-hidden px-3 py-2.5 bg-background', className)}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}

And the Textarea component:
import * as React from 'react'

import { cn } from '@/utils/utils'

export interface TextareaProps extends React.TextareaHTMLAttributes<HTMLTextAreaElement> {}

const Textarea = React.forwardRef<HTMLTextAreaElement, TextareaProps>(
  ({ className, ...props }, ref) => {
    return (
      <textarea
        className={cn(
          'flex w-full rounded-md border border-input bg-transparent px-2 py-1 text-sm shadow-sm placeholder:text-muted-foreground focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-1 focus-visible:ring-ring disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:opacity-50',
          className
        )}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
)
Textarea.displayName = 'Textarea'

export { Textarea }


    import { Textarea, TextareaProps } from '@/components/ui/textarea'
import { useBounds } from '@/hooks/bounds'
import { cn } from '@/utils/utils'
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

interface IProps extends TextareaProps {
  isLoading?: boolean
  formRef?: React.RefObject<HTMLFormElement>
}

export const Input = ({ className, isLoading, formRef, ...rest }: IProps) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLTextAreaElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const textarea = ref.current

      textarea.style.height = 'auto' // Reset height to auto to correctly calculate height
      textarea.style.height = `${textarea.scrollHeight}px` // Set height to scrollHeight
    }
  }, [rest.value])

  const { isDesktop } = useBounds()

  return (
    <Textarea
      rows={1}
      ref={ref}
      onInput={() => { // Listen for input event
        if (ref.current) {
          const textarea = ref.current
          textarea.style.height = 'auto' // Reset height to auto to correctly calculate height
          textarea.style.height = `${textarea.scrollHeight}px` // Set height to scrollHeight
        }
      }}
      onKeyDown={e => {
        if(isDesktop && e.key.toLowerCase() === 'enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
          e.preventDefault();
          formRef?.current?.requestSubmit();
        }
      }}
      className={cn('resize-none overflow-y-hidden px-3 py-2.5 bg-background', className)}
      {...rest}
    />
  )
}


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
